# How to get the component ID in a JSP using DXA 1.2?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.2

I have a requirement where i need to use unique ID for each section rendered on the page. I thought of using TCM id of the component and tried to fetch that as
`<span data-compId=${entity.ID}>` in a JSP. But i am not able to fetch the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DXA decomposes TCM URIs; the ID of Entity Models correspond to the item reference ID of the TCM URI of the Component. In case of a DCP, the Entity Model ID is a combination of Component and Template ID.

Furthermore, you will find TCM URIs in the `XpmMetadata` but that is intended for (guess what?) XPM and not included on a Live environment.

Here’s an example of an Entity View that uses the Entity Model ID to construct an HTML ID: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.2/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Entity/Carousel.jsp

P.S. DXA 1.2? Wow, that’s ancient! Considered upgrading?

Comment: Thanks Rick for your response. As per the reference jsp that you have given ${entity.id} has to work.  Sure, we have a plan for upgrade. Hope it will happen soon :)